# What is the preferred method of handling missing or otherwise unavailable keys in a web.config

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

In my web.config, appSettings section, I have several keys. What is the preferred way to handle in code any keys that are missing? For example, a key name is changed due to a typo. I know I can use various methods to test if the values of said keys exist but what about the key itself?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question -- it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` (requires `System.Configuration` assembly reference) will return `null` if the key is not found.

In that case, I `throw` an instance of my own `MyAppConfigurationException` with something helpful: like *Couldn't open repository, configuration key RepositoryAccess.Customer was not found*.

Hope that helps!